# Convert date with 'May' to number format doesn't work in R

Tags: r, as.date

I am wondering why the following works

```
as.Date("07Jan2013", "%d%B%Y")
"2013-01-07"
```

but, this doesn't

```
as.Date("07May2013", "%d%B%Y")
NA
```

Only the month May gives this issue.

Comment: `as.Date("07May2013", "%d%B%Y")` works for me.

Comment: This is helpful; must be my settings then

Comment: locale settings probably. It works for me after I run `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")` before I get just `NA` like you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to local date. Please try this code from `as.Date` help :

```
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
x <- "07May2013"
z <- as.Date(x, "%d%B%Y")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct) #set locale back
z
> "2013-05-07"
```

I suppose that `as.Date("07Jan2013", "%d%B%Y")`is working because Jan is `Janvier` in French, same prefix than `January`